# Automatically growing label in Python Tkinter (just for fun)

Tags: python, tk

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class GrowLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Label.__init__(self, master)
        self.counter = 12
        self.config(text=str(self.counter), fg="blue", font=("verdana", self.counter, "bold"))
        self.pack()
        button = Button(self.master, text="Stop", command=self.master.destroy)
        button.pack()

    def count(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.config(text=str(self.counter), fg="blue", font=("verdana", self.counter, "bold"))
        self.after(1000, self.count)

label = GrowLabel(root)
label.count()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Naming

Nouns are best for class names instead of verbs.
`GrowLabel` sounds like an action.
`GrowingLabel` would sound like a label that grows.

Related to this,
having a `count` method on a `GrowingLabel` object doesn't sound natural.
The fact that you implement the growing effect using a count should be an internal detail,
and not revealed to users of the class.
The important point is that the label can grow,
not how it does it.
So, renaming the method to `grow()` would be more natural.

#### Calling super-class methods

Since you are in Python 3,
it would be better to call the super constructor of `GrowLabel` like this:

```
super().__init__(master)
```

If that doesn't work somehow (I don't have `tkinter` to try),
then try this instead:

```
super(GrowLabel, self).__init__(master)
```

See more details in this [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482953/python-extending-with-using-super-python-3-vs-python-2).

#### Avoid wildcard imports

Don't use wildcard imports like this:

> ```
> from tkinter import *
> ```

Quoting from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

I guess you do this because you're using many classes from this module.
A better way would be to do like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

And then you can prefix the classes you need with `tk.`, like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

Comment: What's the difference between `super().__init__`, `super(GrowingLabel).__init__` and `super(GrowingLabel, self).__init__`?

Comment: `super().__init__` is the same (more modern) as `super(GrowingLabel, self).__init__`. I didn't know this until you asked, I updated my post now accordingly. I don't know what is `super(GrowingLabel).__init__`